# Bluetooth connection from an android App to Lego Mindstorm EV3 brick

Tags: android, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms, lejos-nxj

I am trying to create an Android App that sents small integers to my EV3 brick, so it can do Actions based on those numbers.
My Problem ist that I can not create a Bluetooth Connection to the Brick in my own App. Has anybody experience with that and knows which sockets or libarys i should use to get that working? I am using the lejos 0.8 api on my brick.